# Warning when using dagger: "@Component.Builder has setters for modules or components that aren't required"

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement new features using Dagger.

**My code**

```
object File {

    lateinit var component: Component

    fun initialize(@NotNull context: Context) {


        component = DaggerFile_Component
            .builder()
            .context(context)
            .build()

    }

    @dagger.Component(modules = [Module::class])

    interface Component {
        fun uploadFile(): UploadFile
        fun awsService(): AwsService
        fun glideLoad(): GlideLoad

        @dagger.Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindsInstance
            fun context(context: Context): Builder

            fun build(): Component
        }

    }


    @dagger.Module
    internal abstract class Module {

        @Binds
        internal abstract fun bindUploadFile(uploadFileImp: UploadFileImp): UploadFile

        @Binds
        internal abstract fun bindAwsService(awsServiceImp: AwsServiceImp): AwsService

        @Binds
        internal abstract fun bindGlideLoad(glideLoadImp: GlideLoadImp): GlideLoad
    }
}
```

While building the project I get:

```
@Component.Builder has setters for modules or components that aren't required
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide `UploadFileImp`, `AwsServiceImp`, `GlideLoadImp` (minimal) implementation? According to [source code](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentDescriptorValidator.java#L291) - it looks like, you provide dependency, that no one of your module consume.

Comment: I would guess that you don't use `Context` anywhere and the warning is there to tell you that. It will probably go away if you actually use `Context` somewhere.

Comment: Do you have any other component in your code?
I don't think this component is causing the issue

Comment: @all : I figured out the issue . I missed to add a component in the AppComponent from another android module . That created true issue.